# Display full names in django form, not username

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django app that has activities and objects that have foreign keys to the User object that is defined in django.contrib.auth.models.  In doing this, I get the `username` property of the user, which is the login id.

Since the User object stores the full name, how do I make a ChoiceField on an form display the full names of the user, not the username, but still link it back to the correct User object after the form is Posted?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not absolutely sure the following works if you have a regular ChoiceField but if you have a modelChoiceField you can do the following:

```
class UserModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    """
    Extend ModelChoiceField for users so that the choices are
    listed as 'first_name last_name (username)' instead of just
    'username'.

    """
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s (%s)" % (obj.get_full_name(), obj.username)


class XYZForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    xyz = UserModelChoiceField(User.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, if you are trying to modify a form in the admin then the XYZForm class should inherit from forms.ModelForm and in admin.py you should make a XYZAdmin class with the form attribute = XYZForm

Answer (score 0):

An easy alternative is to override the `__init__` method of your form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myuserfield'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "%s (%s)" % (obj.get_full_name(), obj.username)
```