# two foreign keys back to User and calling get_full_name in Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Two questions please:

I need two foreign keys back to User, one for author and one for coauthor. I have managed by setting `related_name` equal to + but am not sure if this is smart or the best way.  Thoughts or pointers?

When making an add entry via the django admin for this model, the author choices are names like john_smith, etc. Where would I call get_full_names() from in order to display full names rather than usernames with underscores?  Thanks.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
from django.db import models  
class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()  
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    coauthor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
```

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to the second part of my question (displaying full names instead of usernames in the ChoiceField of a form), I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085627/display-full-names-in-django-form-not-username/) to be just the ticket:

Answer (score 3):

I would change the related name to a value that is more intelligible - such as `books_where_coauthor` and also add a similar one of `books_where_author` as then you can get the relevant books by going from `theuser.books_where_author.all()` etc

Regarding your Admin query, you're getting the username because that's what the default `__unicode__()` method of User spits out.

Unless you'd like to hack your contrib.auth.models file (not recommended), I'd suggest using a custom modelform in the admin, and manually setting the names of the choices in the [ModelChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), either by subclassing that field and making a custom one that renders its widget with `get_full_name` if possible, or do it via something like [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2142/). That said, I am sure there's a simpler way to do that, but I've forgotten. Dangit.

Comment: ps - if you're going to have a large number of Users, I would look at using a raw_id field (google it) instead of a choicefield, else the admin will get really slow...